# Play Framework handling error when using runAsync

Tags: java, playframework-2.5

I have an issue while trying to handle server error on my rest service responsible for data insertion.

```
public CompletableFuture<Result> insertSomething() throws IOException {
    JsonNode jsNode = request().body().asJson();
    format json node to be used
    }
    return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        try {
            service.insertSomething(something);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            internalServerError();
        }
    })
            .thenApply(future -> created("data inserted"))
            .exceptionally(ex -> internalServerError());
}
```

The internalServerError is never thrown and it keep saying "data inserted". Even if I send some data which throws the ParseException. And in debug mode I see it passing in the catch but nothing is thrown.

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer and I just have to instantiate an object of type Throwable in the catch like that:

```
public CompletableFuture<Result> insertSomething() throws IOException {
JsonNode jsNode = request().body().asJson();
format json node to be used
}
return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
    try {
        service.insertSomething(something);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        new Throwable(e.getMessage());
    }
})
        .thenApply(future -> created("data inserted"))
        .exceptionally(ex -> internalServerError());
```

}

Comment: Actually, you're just muffling the `ParseException`.  Did you intend to write a `throw` statement in the `catch` block?  If so, you'll need to throw a `RuntimeException`, and here `CompletionException` is the most appropriate one, e.g. `throw new CompletionException(e);`.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the Exception is catched. If you want to throw an error, you need not to catch it.

Answer (score 0):

Of course nothing is thrown - you catch it? The `exceptionally` will only be executed when inside `runAsync` an exception is thrown *that is not handled* by the code.